# Como deletar um nodo em uma lista encadeada em Java?

Tags: java, lista-encadeada

Tenho o seguinte código em java mas não está funcionando corretamente. Necessito deletar um nodo de uma lista encadeada. Alguém me ajuda?

```
     /*
      Delete Node at a given position in a linked list 
       head pointer input could be NULL as well for empty list
         Node is defined as 
        class Node {
         int data;
         Node next;
     }
     */

   // This is a "method-only" submission. 

   // You only need to complete this method. 

    Node Delete(Node head, int position) {
    // Complete this method
    int cont=1;
    Node tmp=head;
    if(head==null)
    {
    return null;
    }
   if(position==0)
    {
    Node prox= head.next;
    head=prox;
    return head;
  }
  Node tmp=head;
  Node tmp2=head.next;
  while(cont<position)
  {
   tmp=tmp2;
    tmp2=tmp2.next;
    cont++;

 }
 tmp.next=tmp2.next;


 return head;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que assim deve funcionar:

```
public static Node delete(Node head, int position) {
    if (head == null) return null;
    if (position == 0) {
        Node prox = head.next;
        head.next = null;
        return prox;
    }

    int cont = 1;
    Node tmp = head;
    Node tmp2 = head.next;

    while (cont < position) {
        tmp = tmp2;
        tmp2 = tmp2.next;
        cont++;
    }
    tmp.next = tmp2.next;
    tmp2.next = null;
    return head;
 }
```

Havia um erro de compilação porque você declarava `tmp` duas vezes. Havia duas linhas `Node tmp=head;`.

Outra diferenças é que eu faço o nó retirado deixar de apontar para algum ponto no meio da lista ao fazer `noRetirado.next = null;`. Isso ajuda o coletor de lixo e faz com que se houver uma referência ao nó retirado, que ela não possa ser usada para bagunçar com o restante da lista de onde ele foi tirado.

Também mudei o local onde algumas variáveis são declaradas para declará-las somente quando forem se fazer inevitavelmente necessárias.

Comment: Obrigado Victor ! Mas tive uma duvida no primeiro if, você colocou head.next= null ... isso não deletaria a posição 1?

Comment: @YODA Deletaria a posição 0, ou seja, o primeiro nó da lista. Na verdade, ele separa a cabeça do resto e retorna o resto.

Comment: @YODA Ocorre que `head.next = null` faz com que o primeiro nó deixa de conhecer o segundo. Entretanto, o segundo não é perdido porque a referência a ele havia sido armazenada em `prox`, que é o que é retornado.